# Installing psycopg2 in an Azure Web App

Tags: python, django, postgresql, azure, heroku

I use Heroku to host a Django web app with a postgres back-end. I'm now looking to migrate this web app to Azure, taking advantage of a great deal Azure recently offered me.

I've made an Azure Web App, and hosted the postgres DB on a separate Azure VM.

When I try to set up Contiguous Integration in the Azure Web app (connecting it to my github account for the purpose), I end up hitting the error:
**Running setup.py (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\psycopg2\setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2 Error: pg_config executable not found.**

I.e., while installing from requirements.txt, it fails on trying to install psycopg2 (postgresql). I'm trying to figure out what to do next from this point. According to [this](https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows), I'm supposed to run:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win64-py27#egg=psycopg2
```

Now I can't run that in the console I have in my https://webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net; pip is not recognized. Should I edit my requirement.txt directly, and include that line instead of `psycopg2==2.6`? In which case, since it's my master repository, I'll have to remember not to push this new requirements.txt mistakenly to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key points as your missing.

First, Azure Webapps normally run on the 32-bit system platform. If you have to use the 64-bit package, you need to update the Basic or Standard mode for your apps and switch the 64-bit platform, see below in the tab `Configure` of Azure WebApps.

[image]

So you shoule install the psycopg2 version `git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py27#egg=psycopg2`

Second, you can run the pip command in the path `D:\Python27\Scripts>` at Kudu. But unfortunately,  you can't directly install the python package required a compiler thru pip tool. Please refer to the section "Troubleshooting - Package Installation" of the document https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#troubleshooting---package-installation to know how to handle it.

Comment: Hey Peter, if I run the pip command in the path, I'd still have to remove the reference to `psycopg2==2.6` in my `requirements.txt`, correct?

Comment: It seems there are several packages in my `requirements.txt` that don't have wheels (as per pythonwheels.com). I suppose that means even if I do install `psycopg2`, I'll ultimately be stuck. I guess I'm better off just using an Azure VM w/ Ubuntu to host everything, no?

Comment: @HassanBaig Yep. I recommend using Azure VM with Ubuntu to host your application needs.

Comment: Actually, I decided to stick to your advice and see how deep the rabbit hole goes. I've gotten this far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993905/moving-local-whl-file-to-a-folder-on-azure-web-apps-accessed-via-kudu-web-apps Any advice on that?

Comment: @HassanBaig I respect for your decision. I will trying my best to help doing that, althought I never used `psycopg2`. As far as I know, many python packages are not installed into Azure Website because of no permission for  accessing system. Or could you use the other package instead of this one as possible as you can, that can be installed on Azure for accessing postgresql.

Comment: Actually I was able to upload the .whl file in the correct place using FTP. But, I still ended up getting the same error: `Downloading/unpacking psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
  Running setup.py (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\psycopg2\setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...`

Comment: Fixed it. I had built the .whl for 2.6.1, whereas my requirements.txt had 2.6. Done. Your way worked! :-)