# Moving local .whl file to a folder on Azure Web Apps accessed via Kudu (Web Apps' DebugConsole)

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm trying to migrate my Django website from Heroku to Azure. I'm using 'Azure Web Apps', where installing postgresql from my requirements.txt requires a little bit of gymnastics. I can't directly install the package via pip, I instead had to create a [wheel](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#troubleshooting---package-installation) and manually include that in my repository.

I'm halfway done. I have `psycopg2-2.6.1-cp27-none-win32.whl` ready on my local machine. Regarding what to do next, my question is: how do I *copy* the `.whl` file to the relevant folder via Kudu on `https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`? Is there a command for this that'll copy the file from my local machine onto Azure Web Apps?

---

p.s. the folder I'm copying it to is `D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\wheelhouse\`, I hope someone can verify this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to this except good old **FTP**.

In the Azure Web App dashboard in your management portal, go to '**deployment credentials**' and and set an FTP/username and password. Use this pair to connect to the required folders via any FTP client of your choosing. Once in, drag and drop at the relevant location!

Moreover, the correct location to place the .whl files is `D:\home\site\repository\wheelhouse\`

Comment: In the Kudu Debug console CMD directory browser, you can also simply drag/drop files from your local machine into the correct Azure location in folder viewer in the browser.